# How can I pass data of the type byte[] to SQL VarBinary(Max) via stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to store `PasswordHash` and `PasswordSalt` which are of type `byte[]` into the database, and for that I created a stored procedure. But the problem is, when I try to pass their parameters to the stored procedure, `System.byte[]` is received in SQL Server which cannot be stored as `VARBINARY(Max)`.

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<UserRegisterDto>>> Register(string Mobile, string FirstName, string LastName, string Email, int Age, string password)
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<List<UserRegisterDto>>();

    if (await UserExists(Mobile))
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Message = "User already exists.";
        return response;
    }

    CreatePasswordHash(password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);

    var dbUsers = await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($"RegisterNewUser {Mobile}, {FirstName}, {LastName}, {Email}, {Age}, {passwordHash}, {passwordSalt}");
       
    return response;
}
```

Where `CreatePasswordHash` is:

```
private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
{
    using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
    {
        passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
        passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    }
}
```

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegisterNewUser]
    @Mobile NVarChar(100),
    @FirstName NVarChar(250),
    @LastName NVarChar(250),
    @Email NVarChar(250),
    @Age int,
    @PasswordHash VarBinary(max),
    @PasswordSalt VarBinary(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    INSERT INTO Users (Mobile, FirstName, LastName, Email, Age,
                       PasswordHash, PasswordSalt)
    VALUES (@Mobile, @FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @Age,
            @PasswordHash, @PasswordSalt)
```

PS: I don't want to pass them in string format or anything

Comment: You need to **AT LEAST** show us the stored procedure signature, and how you're calling it from C# - remember: we **CANNOT** see your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to **SHOW US** for us to have **any** chance of helping you!

Comment: @marc_s Code Added!

Comment: Do you get error from the stored procedure?

Comment: @Chetan No Error! It has problem with the type that is passed to

Comment: How do you know `It has problem with the type` ?

Comment: @Chetan Sql server profiler. `system.byte[]` is passed to it

Comment: and you do not see any value in the columns in the database table? Curious, why you do not want to use string?

Comment: @Chetan no value can be inserted in the corresponding columns. When you can store lightweight byte why should you use string?

Comment: Here's a thought: If you don't want to stringify it then don't use an interpolated string to pass the parameter values. `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` does have an overload that takes an array of `SqlParameter` values.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Then What should I use Instead?

Comment: Use the `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` overload that accepts an array of `SqlParameter` values. When creating [`SqlParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter)s you define their names and the specific SQL DB Types that they represent - and you can attach instances of C# `byte[]` directly to an [`SqlDbType.VarBinary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype)'s value field. Special note: SQL DB Types with a `(max)` length specifier use the non-obvious length of `-1` on `SqlParameter` instances.